# Grails discard domain object

Tags: grails, grails-domain-class

```
void businessMethod(def object) {
    // invoke discard only on hibernate objects
    if (isDomainObject(object))
        object.discard()
    // other stuff
}
```

How could I verify if object is grails domain object and is managed by hibernate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try

```
grailsApplication.domainClasses*.clazz.contains(Hibernate.getClass(object))
```

see:http://grails.1312388.n4.nabble.com/Check-if-object-is-a-domain-instance-td3224172.html

Answer (score 1):

```
    if (object.metaClass.respondsTo(object, "discard")) {
        object.discard()
    }
```